# Simple Expand/Collapse divs > JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to add some accordian style expand/collapse handles to a series of parent container divs in my application. Is this something that's too simple for a library like jquery?

Example:

```
<div class="handleDiv"> expand | collapse
    <div>child element</div>
    <div>child element</div>
</div>

<div class="handleDiv"> expand | collapse
    <div>child element</div>
    <div>child element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: Is this markup set in stone, or do you have control over it? e.g. Could you wrap the child elements in a container div?

Comment: @Nick: I have complete control of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.handleDiv').click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();
});
```

That'll expand or hide the contents of the "handleDiv"s whenever you click them. I'd suggest making those "expand | collapse" things links and attaching the click handler to them, though, so that a click anywhere in the div doesn't toggle it.

If you want them to start out closed, either style them closed in your stylesheet:

```
.handleDiv div {
    display: none;
}
```

or add a ".hide()" to the end of the jQuery snippet at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: I think you want `.handleDiv div` there on the CSS

Answer (score 4):

I have just wrote a plugin to do that.

See http://sylvain-hamel.github.io/simple-expand/

Comment: This plugin is excellent but beginners should note that the script `<script>$('.expander').simpleexpand();</script>` should be put at the bottom of the page (just before the `</body>` tag).

Comment: I'm glad the plug-in helped. You can put this script tag anywhere you want. But make sure the call is wrapped in jQuery `DOM ready` callback: `<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('.expander').simpleexpand(); }); </script>`. This is the case for pretty much every thing jQuery related.

Comment: Sylvain is correct, however as a noob I did have to try putting the   <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('.expander').simpleexpand(); }); </script>
 in various different locations and in the head is the only time it worked for me. (e.g. putting it into a rails erb partial in my case did not work)